# Texto dentro do cardview pela metade

Tags: android, android-layout

Gostaria de saber como coloco o texto dentro de um cardview mais para cima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu código está assim:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView26"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="DETALHES"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Coloque também o código do seu cardView

Comment: **Edite sua pergunta** colocando seus códigos para complementar... Mas pelo que eu dei uma rápida olhada, posso estar enganado, mas você definiu a altura do cardView como 50dp, definiu para centralizar o que tiver dentro dele e está usando um padding de 10dp que está empurrando seu `textView`, e como ele é **Large**, acaba ficando cortado...

Comment: Tente dar um paddingBottom, vai resolver esse problema, você pode ir testando como fica pelo próprio preview do Android Studio

Comment: @Furflez fiz o que você solicitou. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @LeonardoDias coloquei assim no código  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" e ficou a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 2):

A altura do CardView está definida com `50dp` o que parece não ser suficiente para a altura do texto.

Defina a altura do CardView, RelativeLayout e TextView como `wrap_content`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView26"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="DETALHES"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Estava esquecendo de modificar o Relative Layout também. Resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado pela ajuda.